# Change ArrayList to three dots for an input

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

I have a method that has as a signature, let's say `method(Object... args)`
And one of my other methods creates an `ArrayList<Object> list`.

What should I do so I can use `method(list)`?
I have tried to do `method(Arrays.asList(list))` but it has not worked

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`List.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) like

```
method(list.toArray());
```

Also, the three dots means it is a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) or [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).